# Which price format is more readable for car sites

Tags: money, currency

In India car prices are mostly above Rs 1,00,000. Rs 1,00,000 is also called as 1 Lac or [Lakh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh) in India.

Suppose a car is worth Rs 3,80,000. What will be the most suitable option, 
3.8 Lacs or 3,80,000?

Comment: **Note**: To readers unfamiliar with Lakh and Crore or with a system that uses something other than thousands grouping (000), numbers such as the ones in this question (1,00,000 and 3,80,000) may appear to be incorrect. They're not.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of readability, the longer version of the number is more readable and easier for people to compare.

In terms of suggesting value, setting something at 3.8 Lacs might make people think it's less than Rs 380,000.

I've not read any research behind it, but from experience it works with dates.  People would rather say something is 2 weeks away than 14 days.  There's more of a focus on the number rather than the unit.

Is the lac a legitimate unit, or is it common slang?  In the UK, people know that 1K is 1,000; but prices for cars are always* listed as the expanded version.  You'll see prices for £12,000 and not £12k.  Oddly (as a side note) mileage is generally rounded to the nearest thousand, and listed in the short format, e.g. 44K

*from every car dealer, website and manufacturer I've ever looked at; and I car browse far more than I should.

Comment: This answer conflicts with another. For credibility, can you add any sources to add source to your answer? Links to specific sites? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @gabe3886 I thought 3.8Lacs looks *lesser* in value than 3,80,000! Which looks more? 1 Billion USD or 1,000,000,000 USD ?

Comment: "2 weeks away than 14 days. There's more of a focus on the number rather than the unit"    Agreed.

Answer (score 1):

For the prices in India using decimal format is more acceptable since people are more used to it. You should use units up to 2 decimal points, **it is more readable as well**

> for example 3.80Lacs

Here are a few Indian websites examples for reference : [Carwale](http://www.carwale.com/), [Cardekho](http://www.cardekho.com/)

**Both of the formats have their significance. When and if comparing prices, you can use long format. Long format can also be used when adding up the price of accessories.**

> for example Ex-Showroom Price + Accessories = 3,80,000 + 3,500

Comment: This answer conflicts with another. For credibility, can you add any sources to add source to your answer? Links to specific sites? Thanks in advance.